# Adapting an outside wall outlet to suface mount conduit?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, outdoor, conduit, weather-resistant

This was a previous question with some great answers.
[How can I adapt a wall outlet to suface mount conduit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49997/how-can-i-adapt-a-wall-outlet-to-suface-mount-conduit/100795#100795)
One answer was: "There are collar boxes available that have conduit KO's (knockouts). Just install one on top of the existing device box and run your conduit."
I was wondering if there was a way to do this while maintain weather proofing of the outlet for outside applications? Is there a gasket box extender that could be used? I have a plug I would like to adapt to conduit that is on a partially covered porch. It would not be exposed directly to rain or weather but could potentially get wet.[image]

Comment: If it can get wet a handy box with knockouts would not meet code a weather tight box and in-use cover would be needed. The conduit screws into the box and create a seal where the boxes with KO's can leak. The KO's can allow water in even if not removed. There are weather tight extensions available. A photo would help us point you in the correct way.

Comment: This is not the exact plug I would be adapting but is a good representation of the outlet I am talking about. The outlet I would be adapting is on a three walled porch so it would be more protected. It would really only get wet when we use a hose to rinse out the area. It is outside the house though and I would like it protected. Currently there is only a normal outlet in it with no weather protection. I would like to run another outlet to the second wall and in the process would like to improve the original plugs weather protection.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate [extension box will look like this](https://www.zoro.com/bell-weatherproof-box-1gang-6inlet-5400-0/i/G0643982/?gclid=CJOy39Od088CFQeVfgodfm8HHQ&gclsrc=aw.ds). Hole plugs in unused openings then conduit can be run on the surface for an additional outlet with a weather tight box.

Comment: How do you seal that? assuming the area where it meets is outside where any normal caulk around lines would be

Comment: Calk around the edge of the box would be fine at the extension to the wall. The extensions that have openings are threaded so threaded fittings can be used. The extension it self comes with foam seals that are listed for this use.