# Outlet to conduit junction recommendations

Tags: electrical, conduit

I've got a recessed outlet box on the outside of my house. To be more specific the outlet (when removing the weatherproof cover assembly) is flush with the stucco. I need to decommission this as an outlet and run conduit along the wall around 6ft to the left of it.

I was thinking of using this:

[image]

and simply putting a right angle flex line attachment into one of the threads and carry along.

Example (forget the 10awg): https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-6-ft-10-Gauge-3-Conductor-Non-metallic-Liquidtight-A-C-Whip/3616544

I found this: [Adapting an outside wall outlet to suface mount conduit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100802/adapting-an-outside-wall-outlet-to-suface-mount-conduit)

But I'm not sure that is a good approach considering the leakage potential.

Thoughts or better methods would be appreciated? Is what I plan to do a good option?

Comment: That non-metallic whip is for connecting a/c units and is not approved for an extension along a wall to a new receptacle. Experts here will tell you what the approved choices are.

Comment: That cover is for sticking a motion sensor and a couple of bug-eye floodlights on.  You've seen motion sensor lights preassembled that are exactly that.  They do make junction box covers specifically for coming off with conduit, they have a 1/2" KO in their center.

Comment: @Harper that's exactly what I was looking for. Can you find an example? I couldn't find one

Comment: Under the principle that you can't have too many receptacles, why not keep the receptacle there and extend to the new location with conduit? You already have a penetration there so make use of it with the rectangular extension box with a receptacle in it and extend with conduit.

Answer (score 3):

I think the [rectangular box extension](https://www.zoro.com/bell-weatherproof-box-1gang-6inlet-5400-0/i/G0643982/?gclid=CJOy39Od088CFQeVfgodfm8HHQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) is better. It seems to me to be better to just come straight out of the old receptacle parallel to the wall. Are there even fittings to adapt to that angle of the one you are picturing?

Comment: I suggested a box extension to the original question. I agree this would be better, and pvc from the extension to the new location. It can be used for this but electricians usually would not because of the cost. I am not sure if the fixture base is listed for conduit would be a concern other than looking like a hack job with that and flex.